# Logs of Token couldn't be received

Tags: logs

I am using Ethereum Wallet Version 0.8.9 on Ubuntu 16.04. I added Golem token to Wallet about week ago and now I get following error messages on logs:

[ERROR] (ui: browser) - Logs of Token Golem Network Token couldn't be received {}

Is this something that I should address or just ignore? Everything seems to work as it should. Error is added to log every second, so I don't want to keep my wallet open so that log size wont grow too big.